# Fullcalendar 5 resourceLabelContent return promise

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar 5 with Angular.
I want to display a custom resource label based on data from database. I use the resource render hook **resourceLabelContent** with returning an HTML string.
In order to get the data I need, I must to define the function as an **asynchronous function** with the use of **async** and **await** (see code example below).

My problem is : as soon as I add the keyword async to my function, resources labels aren't displaying anymore. I think it's because the function is now returning a Promise and not a "{ html : '..' }.

What I want to do : I have users who are attached to different places (resources) according to the dates. I want to display the name of the users below the resource label using resourceLabelContent. I must therefore request my database to retrieve them and so make an asynchronous request.

Is there a way to display resources label with async function or should I avoid it ?

Code example :

```
async resourceLabelContent(info) {    

  const date = info.date;
  const usersAvailable= await this.service.getUsersAvailable(date, info.resource.id);

  return { html: '<span>'+ usersAvailable+'</span> }
}
```

Just in case, how I bind my function :

```
this.calendarOptions.resourceLabelContent = this.resourceLabelContent.bind(this);
```

**EDIT** : In order to be clearer, I've added a description of what I need to do with resourceLabelContent

Answer (score -2):

Since your function is `async`, is returns a `Promise`. So, in order to use it, you have to change your calling code

```
resourceLabelContent()
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data)) // <-- Here is your expected data
```

Give it a try!

Comment: in the function itself or when i bind it to the calendar ?

Comment: Just try like this. Also, please reproduce this in CodeSandbox so that community can see and play around

Comment: In fact, I don't see where to do your solution. The only time i call resourceLabelContent is when i bind it to the calendar and adding "then()..." just show an error.

Comment: This answer makes no sense in the context of the fullCalendar callback. By the time then `then` would execute, the `resourceLabelContent` callback function would already have finished executing and no output would have been returned to it. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection explains how these callbacks work. There's no mention of support for Promises or async. Also `resourceLabelContent()` isn't a function you can execute. I don't think you understood the question properly. Are you familiar with fullCalendar?

Comment: No support of Promises or async , does it mean i can't make asynchronous call in it and I must find another way to do what i need ?